# Why is $DATA empty when downloading a file via UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, download, alternate-data-stream

I'm experiencing an issue while downloading an exe file from within an UWP App. The EXE cannot be run after downloading. When I download it via any browser, it works as expected. My research so far brought me to Alternate Data Streams.
When I download the EXE via any browser, the file gets an ADS like My.EXE:Zone.Identifier:$DATA with ZoneId=3 and some additional stuff inside.
When I download the same file from my UWP, it's also like My.EXE:Zone.Identifier:$DATA, but $DATA is empty with a size of 0 bytes like in the screenshot.
[image]

Did anyone experience the same issue and found a solution? Any hint would be great.

EDIT[Code added]:

```cs
        private async void Download_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(resourceLoader.GetString("Link"));
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
        }
```

Comment: What api you used to download file? Could you please provide us the code snippet you used? In addition, I suggest that you could create a new Blank app to test whether this error also occurs.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT, thanks for your answer. I added the code-part in my question. From my understanding there's nothing special on that Launcher, but I'm not a pro.